# How do you rotate the axis of a plot in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following plot done in Plotly

[image: A plot]

As you can see the X,Y axis are in the traditional way.
How can I rotate the axis so that X is plot vertically and Y horizontally (to the left)?

(also I would like to modify the reach and separations of each axis)

I suppose it has to do something with the layout element.

My code if so far

```
layout= go.Layout(title=go.layout.Title(text=title,x=0.5),
        xaxis={'title':'x[m]'},
        yaxis={'title':'y[m]'})

    point_plot=[
            go.Scatter(x=[series[listoflabels[0]]],y=[series[listoflabels[1]]],name="V0"),
            go.Scatter(x=[series[listoflabels[2]]],y=[series[listoflabels[3]]],name="GT"),
            go.Scatter(x=[0],y=[0],name="egoCar")
            ]

    return go.Figure(data=point_plot, layout=layout)
```

EDIT:

In order to make it reproducible I modified the code to

```
layout1= go.Layout(title=go.layout.Title(text="A graph",x=0.5),
        xaxis={'title':'x[m]'},
        yaxis={'title':'y[m]'})

point_plot=[
            go.Scatter(x=[3],y=[1],name="V0"),
            go.Scatter(x=[5],y=[2],name="GT"),
            go.Scatter(x=[0],y=[0],name="egoCar")
    ]
            
go.Figure(data=point_plot, layout=layout1).show()
```

and the plot is

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could modify your code so it's reproducible? I know if plotly graph object but also the title and then who knows what else.

Comment: @hrokr I edited it to the minimum necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware that Plotly has any built-in method to switch x- and y-axes. However, you can achieve this yourself but switching the titles of the x- and y-axes, then switching the parameters `x` and `y` that correspond to your points.

Then you can place the y-axis (containing your x-coordinates) on the right side in your layout, and reverse the range of the x-axis (containing your y-coordinates) so that the origin is in the lower-right side.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# switch the axes titles
layout1= go.Layout(title=go.layout.Title(text="A graph",x=0.5),
        xaxis={'title':'y[m]'},
        yaxis={'title':'x[m]', 'side':'right'})

# switch the x- and y-coordinates
point_plot=[
            go.Scatter(y=[3],x=[1],name="V0"),
            go.Scatter(y=[5],x=[2],name="GT"),
            go.Scatter(y=[0],x=[0],name="egoCar")
    ]


fig = go.Figure(data=point_plot, layout=layout1)

# reverse the range of the xaxis (which contains the y values)
fig.update_xaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working. However I have still a problem, and I will post it as a question. I would appreciate if you can take a look

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer. Just to notice that the `autorange="reversed"` can be replaced by 'autorange=[(positive number),(negative number)]` if we want to have the range manually set.

Answer (score 1):

Derek O hit on what is the easiest to implement. It's the graph analogy of 1km is 0.6 miles or `a, b = b, a`

A second option is to abstract the data and your axes. That's essentially saying the same thing but can be easier to read as Plotly has a unique ability to turn clear, well-structured Python into ugly JS without parenthesis pretty quickly.

Option three is to further abstract this and have it set your axes for you.